# Extract the numbers in a string from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, feature-extraction

I need to do feature extraction using the column 'Amenities' from the dataframe house_price.

The column Amenities has the following set of data

```
house_data['Amenities']

3                       3 beds 1 bath
4              1 bed 1 bath 1 parking
5                       3 beds 1 bath
6            2 beds 2 baths 2 parking
7             3 beds 1 bath 2 parking
                    ...              
2096    3 beds 2 baths 1 parking 419m
2097          4 beds 1 bath 2 parking
2098         3 beds 2 baths 2 parking
2099         2 beds 2 baths 1 parking
2100    3 beds 2 baths 1 parking 590m
Name: Amenities, Length: 1213, dtype: object
```

I need to extract the number of beds, baths and parkings and store them into 3 seperate columns.

```
house_data["bedrooms"] = ''
house_data["bedrooms"] = house_data["Amenities"].str.extract("(\d*\.?\d+)", expand=True)



3       3
4       1
5       3
6       2
7       3
       ..
2096    3
2097    4
2098    3
2099    2
2100    3
Name: bedrooms, Length: 1213, dtype: object
```

The above code extracts only the first digit of the entire string. How can I extract the digits representing the number of baths/parking and store them under different columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `named groups` here with `Series.str.extract`:

```
regex = r'(?P<beds>\d)\sbeds?\s(?P<bath>\d+)\sbaths?\s?(?P<parking>\d)?'
df = pd.concat([df, df['Amenities'].str.extract(regex)], axis=1)

                       Amenities beds bath parking
0                  3 beds 1 bath    3    1     NaN
1         1 bed 1 bath 1 parking    1    1       1
2                  3 beds 1 bath    3    1     NaN
3       2 beds 2 baths 2 parking    2    2       2
4        3 beds 1 bath 2 parking    3    1       2
5  3 beds 2 baths 1 parking 419m    3    2       1
6        4 beds 1 bath 2 parking    4    1       2
7       3 beds 2 baths 2 parking    3    2       2
8       2 beds 2 baths 1 parking    2    2       1
9  3 beds 2 baths 1 parking 590m    3    2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df = df['Amenities'].str.split(r'[a-zA-Z ]+', expand=True).drop(columns=[3, 4])
print(df)

   0  1  2
0  3  1   
1  1  1  1
2  3  1   
3  2  2  2
4  3  1  2
5  3  2  1
6  4  1  2
7  3  2  2
8  2  2  1
9  3  2  1
```